# Prove $n! > 2^n-1$ for $ n \geq 4$

Tags: inequality

Prove $n! > 2^n-1$ for $ n \geq 4$

Base Case - $(n=4)$ $\implies$ $24 >15$

Assume true for $n=k$ $\implies$ 
$$k! > 2^k -1$$
$$(k+1)k! > 2^k-1$$
$$(k+1)! > 2^{k}-1$$
$$2(k+1)! > 2^{k+1}-2$$
$$2(k+1)! > (2^{k+1}-1)-1$$

I'm not sure how to continue now..

Comment: When you multiply the left side by $k+1$, also multiply the right side by $k+1$.  Then use that $k+1>2$.  Finally, use that $(k+1)!$ is even, while $2^{k+1}-1$ is odd.

Comment: @SteveD If the LHS is already increasing (we assumed that) do we really need to multiply by RHS by that as well?

Comment: Isn’t it easier to show $n!>2^n$, which is also true, more straightforward to show, and implies the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you didn't had a mistake, but the way is not the right approach:

if you assume it is true for $n=k$ to show it is true for $k+1$ you need to show that:$$(k+1)!\ge2^{k+1}-1\\\text{we can do the following: }(k+1)k!\ge(k+1)\times\left(2^{k}-1\right)\gt2\times\left(2^{k}-1\right)$$ because we assumed that $k!\ge2^k-1$ for $k\ge4$ if we show that $k+1\gt2$(which is true) we get $(k+1)!\gt2^{k+1}-2$ because both are even and $(k+1)!\ne2^{k+1}-2$ i can add one to the right side and i get $$(k+1)!\gt2^{k+1}-1$$and you had shown it is true to $k=4$ thus it is true $\forall k\ge4$

Comment: What does both being even mean you can add one to both sides? I still don't get that :(

Comment: @dydxx if i have 2 even numbers that are not equal, it means that one is greater than the other by at least 2 right? we know that the right side is less than the left side, so it is less by at least 2, so if i add 1, it will still be less by at least 1

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
(k+1)k! &> (k+1)(2^k-1)\\
&> 2(2^k-1)\\
&> 2^{k+1}-2
\end{align}

Thus $(k+1)!\ge 2^{k+1}-1$, but the left side is even while the right side is odd, so equality is not an option, and $(k+1)!>2^{k+1}-1$.

Comment: How did u know $(k+1)! > 2^{k+1} - 1$

Comment: Let a b be integers if a>b the a>=b-1

Answer (score 2):

You are making it more difficult than it needs to be. The $n! > 2^n -1$ is in integers the same as $n! \geq 2^n $. This bound is sharper, and you get rid of the annoying $-1$. Notice that the induction step is then simply $$(n+1)! = (n+1) n! \geq 2\cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1 },$$ where we used $n+1\geq 2$ and the induction hypothesis $n! \geq 2^n$.

Comment: How do you get the last inequality?

Comment: I think there is -1 missing

Comment: @GuyFsone Where? The point of this answer is to get rid of the $-1$ by replacing $> $ with $\geq$.

Comment: I see thanks just update your post plz

Comment: Edited. Gosh its so annoying to typeset from phone..

Comment: I did for you. I know that struggle